# useradd -u issue: User not listed in /etc/group nor /etc/gshadow

Tags: bash, centos, user-management

When running the following line, I expect the new user- user3- to be added with the GID of 1001, but when ran the user is not listed in either the /etc/group nor the /etc/gshadow files:

```
# useradd -u 1010 -g 1001 -m -d /home/user3 -k /etc/skel -s /bin/bash user3
```

Then, when searching for user3, no results are given:

```
# cd /etc; grep user3 group gshadow
```

When grepping for the GID, only the other user- user2- that belongs to that group is found:

```
# cd /etc; grep 1001 group gshadow
group:user2:x:1001:
```

I am currently running:

```
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
3.10.0-514.2.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Dec 6 23:06:41 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

You create new user and add it to existing group with id 1001. It's already exist with it's own name. So that's why you haven't see this user in group or gshadow. If you change group ID in useradd to non-existent group, you could found it after user creation.